# How does calling this function (without a definition) work?

Tags: c++, function, declaration

So I am trying to get to grips with someone's code (and cannot contact them) and I do not understand why they do this. They call a function in main like this:

```
LOG_AddFunction();
```

This function is defined in a header file like this:

```
#define LOG_AddFunction()    LOG_Add(LOG_TYPE_NORMAL, "%s()", __FUNCTION__)
```

Then LOG_Add is defined in the same header file:

```
extern int  LOG_Add(LOG_TYPE eType, const char *pcText, ...);
```

There does not seem to be any ultimate definition of the LOG_AddFunction function and I do not understand why the code calls it. Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Remove the tag for the language in which the code is not written.

Comment: Obviously, `LOG_AddFunction()` is a macro, not a function. And `Log_Add` is only _declared_, not _defined_

Comment: @Olaf: Do not arbitrarily guess at what language the OP is using.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are no C++ specifics in the snippets, so I follow Occam's Razor.

Comment: @Olaf: That's not how tagging works. We tag the language actually being used, not some other language in which the code may happens to do similar or identical things. Cheers

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, if it worked, the tags would jump OP into his face:-) Nevermind.

Comment: The reason I am confused is because this is an engine I am using, in the creators words "based on C/C++". What is Occam's Razor. So this is entirely C++?

Comment: No, the snippets could be either. That is the reason @LightnessRacesinOrbit and I had that short discussion. There is no language "C/C++". These are different languages, so it is you to tell which it is, as you shoul have th code and know how to compile. [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) should be well know to everybody, as it is one basic principle of scientific and engineering thinking.

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie: Only you can tell us how you're compiling the code. Are you writing a C program, or a C++ program? Sadly, the creator of the engine seems confused, which does not bode well. As for "Occam's Razor", Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: Apologies, I am a beginner. It is a C++ program

Comment: I'm a 30-year C programmer and C++ hater, and I have deleted many C++ tags in many questions. But the fact is that the snippets in this question, and the answer to the question, apply 100% equally to both languages. So this is a rare case where both tags are completely correct.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: No, it is not. We do not tag questions based on the argument that "the answer is the same", because the question comes before the answer. In fact you don't know _until_ you answer the question that the answer could fit whether the question were tagged C or C++. The only clear way to do this is to tag the "real, practical problem that you face" with the real, practical language being written. You're putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Perhaps that's good as a general policy, but it makes this final answer less searchable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LOG_AddFunction` is not a function. It is a function-like *macro*. Its only "definition" is exactly what you showed us in the question.

Its purpose is to automatically call `LOG_Add` with the name of the function at the callsite (`__FUNCTION__`) automatically passed. Whenever you write `LOG_AddFunction()`, those characters are automatically replaced by the preprocessor (just as with any other macro) with `LOG_Add(LOG_TYPE_NORMAL, "%s()", __FUNCTION__)`.

This saves typing the whole `LOG_Add` call every time; nothing more.

Comment: But what does LOG_Add actually do? I understand what you have said, an understanding of what the call actually does (by understanding what LOG_Add actually does) is enough for me to accept the answer

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie: Adds to a log, I'd imagine?? Probably so a developer can track function calls. Not sure what else you expect me to say about code I cannot see. You only asked about `LOG_AddFunction`, so requiring an explanation of `LOG_Add` for an accept seems dishonest.

Comment: When I requested an "ultimate definition of LOG_AddFunction" it was because I could not understand what LOG_Add does, and this is the definition.Could you explain what the current call would do given that there is no definition of LOG_Add?

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie: There is a definition of `LOG_Add` somewhere. Only you can determine where it is. We cannot magically divine this information!